# Migrating non-WordPress CMS to WordPress, lots of data to move -- possible solutions?

Tags: database, post-meta, mysql, migration, cms

I have a custom CMS, that we're looking to port over into Wordpress. (I can see you asking yourself:

> *Why not just stick with the custom CMS?*

Well, it's outdated, clunky, and getting to be too much of a hassle to maintain; there are also many features of WordPress that we would really like to take advantage of.

**So here's the issue** -- We have a main type of content (let's call them *Tours*). Each Tour has about 30 pieces of metadata associated with it (all currently different columns on the `Tours` table). We currently have about 600,000 Tours.

Each Tour has several different types of images associated to it, from *Interior Images*, to *Exterior*, to *Floor Plans*, etc. Each *Image* has about 10 pieces of metadata associated with it (again, all currently columns on the `Images` table). We currently have about **7 million Images in our system**.

You can likely see our problem -- if we put all Tours and Images into the default `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` table, we're going to end up with *millions of rows* in `wp_posts`, and far more than that in the `wp_postmeta` table. I'm not sure how much mySQL can handle as far as numbers of rows, but it seems likely that we will reach a slowdown point, especially when querying the `wp_postmeta` table.

My questions:

1. One possibility we've discussed is only holding **"active" Tours** in the `wp_posts` and archiving older Tours to a separate table. Is anyone aware of any plugins that do anything like this?
2. Another possibility is putting the Tours into the `wp_posts` table, and keeping the Images separate from that. One thing we would really like to use, though, is the Wordpress image uploader. Is there anyway to override where the image data is saved?
3. Any other suggestions of how we might best implement this much data into Wordpress?

Comment: Be careful of the exponential number of files that will be created by importing images into WP. Plugins/themes register new image sizes and each image size gets its own resize/crop file in the file system. 7 Million images X 4 default WP sizes is quite mind boggling to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest inserting your tours as posts (or custom posts) and using a custom reference table with the id matching the post id of the Tour post.

You could use Wordpress's built in meta box functions to be able to edit each Tour in the edit posts page.

You could update your reference table by hooking into the 'save_post' action.

There will be a considerable look-up speed improvement if you choose to create this reference table as MYISAM and use fixed column widths along with indexing searchable columns.

With that much data, you could use this option to not only tap in to much of the great Wordpress built-in functionality, but ensure speedy look-ups on the extra data.

Comment: So to make sure I understand what you're saying, you're suggesting putting the Tours in the wp_posts table, and then storing all the data that _would_ normally go into wp_postmeta into its own separate table? That's definitely doable, and would make data retrievable more manageable (and more searchable). 

What are your thoughts on the Images? They're the bulk of the data, actually, and putting each of them in as an attachment to the Tour is really going to bulk up the wp_posts table.

Comment: I would suggest storing them on the server in numbered file folders referring to the post id of the 'Tour'. Then you would only need to store their file name in the reference table.  That way you can still keep the look-ups fast. Hope that helps (Its the way I handle large sets of data myself with Wordpress)

Comment: Also, if you need some guidance on some of the functions involved, I could help with the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to http://podsframework.org/. It's a custom post type enhancer that allows you even to create a stand alone table for every kind of object you need.